# DialogFragment layout change animation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I have a DialogFragment whose layout params I'm changing from `[MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT]` to `[MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT]` on a button click. Basically, the dialog fragment goes from a small dialog to fullscreen. I would like for this to be animated and just not a quick jump. I'm currently just doing in the onClickListener

```
getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(mExpandedParams.width, mExpandedParams.height);
```

Is there someway I can get the transition to be a smooth animation?